# Click on the "Cancel" for "Start a bounty" scrolls page to the top

Tags: bug, bounties

If I close "Start a bounty" window with a "Cancel" button, page scrolls to the top.

> [image: start a bounty]

This is not happen if I choose close button (right top) or simply click anywhere on the page outside this window.